# why region_code not storing properly in magento 2.3.5?

Tags: magento2, customer, api, customer-address, graphql

I am using [Magento GraphQL](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/index.html) api in my project. To create a customer address I used `createCustomerAddress` mutation([createCustomerAddress](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/create-customer-address.html)).

Below is the mutation that I have called to create the customer address :

```
mutation createAddress {
  createCustomerAddress(
    input: {
      firstname: "test"
      lastname: "name"
      company: "networld"
      telephone: "1231231231"
      street: ["test address line 1", "test address line 2"]
      city: "Rajkot"
      region: { region:"Gujarat", region_code: "GJ" }
      postcode: "360001"
      country_code: IN
    }
  ) {
    id
    prefix
    firstname
    lastname
    middlename
    city
    company
    country_code
    default_billing
    default_shipping
    postcode
    region {
      region
      region_code
    }
    street
    suffix
    telephone
    vat_id
  }
}
```

This is working properly and returning me the result as below :

```
{
  "data": {
    "createCustomerAddress": {
      "id": 44,
      "prefix": null,
      "firstname": "test",
      "lastname": "name",
      "middlename": null,
      "city": "Rajkot",
      "company": "networld",
      "country_code": "IN",
      "default_billing": false,
      "default_shipping": false,
      "postcode": "360001",
      "region": {
        "region": "Gujarat",
        "region_code": "GJ"
      },
      "street": [
        "test address line 1",
        "test address line 2"
      ],
      "suffix": null,
      "telephone": "1231231231",
      "vat_id": null
    }
  }
}
```

But, now when I query to get the customer address, it returning wrong `region_code`.

Here is the query I written to get the customer address :

```
query{
  customer{
    addresses{
      id
      firstname
      lastname
      street
      city
      region{
        region
        region_code
      }
      country_code
      postcode
      telephone
    }
  }
}
```

Result :

```
{
  "data": {
    "customer": {
      "addresses": [
        {
          "id": 44,
          "firstname": "test",
          "lastname": "name",
          "street": [
            "test address line 1",
            "test address line 2"
          ],
          "city": "Rajkot",
          "region": {
            "region": "Gujarat",
            "region_code": "Gujarat"
          },
          "country_code": "IN",
          "postcode": "360001",
          "telephone": "1231231231"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `region_code` in this query result and `region_code` in mutation result was different. Query not returning `region_code` that generated from the mutation. Mutation generated `region_code` was **GJ** and query returned `region_code` was **Gujarat**.

Can anyone help me why this is happening ? How to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your query. It seems like you will have pass one additional field while calling "**createCustomerAddress**" mutation within "region" array. You will have to pass "**region_id**" along with "region" and "region_code" in that array.

**Like this :**

```
region: {
      region: "Georgia"
      region_code: "GA"
      region_id:19
    }
```

If you pass like this then you will get the exact region code as "GA" in customer query which you call after this. I have already done this practise in my Altair. It should work fine for you as well.

FYI : My magento2 version is 2.3.3

Thanks,

Comment: Ok, but in document it displaying that `region_id` is deprecated, 
"region_id is deprecated. Region ID is excessive on storefront and region code should suffice for all scenarios".

Comment: And, no problem if it is deprecated, but from where I can get `region_id` for perticular region ?

Comment: @KishanBharda, yes it might be deprecated and that's why I have posted my magento version along with the answer. If you are ready to accept this and want to pass region_id then you can find it from the region dropdown on checkout page. In region dropdown you should have value and label fields. In value the region id will be there and in label region label will be there. If you want to check in database then you will find it in this table "directory_country_region". Hope this help to you. Thanks!

Comment: I am also on version 2.3.5. And I am using this api to develop a mobile app of a magento site. So, there is an issue to get `region_id`. However there is an api to get countries and region which returning region_id also. So, that can be helpful. But still I have to use deprecated field to solve this. Any solution without using deprecated field?

Comment: I don't think that you will face any problem if you use this because magento has also listed it on devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/create-customer-address.html#customerAddressRegionInput for magento version 2.4. Still, If I will find any other alternative solution then I will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you very much. I know this is workaround solution, but it helps me. However I not accepting this answer for sometime, so If anyone has proper solution, we can get.

Comment: @KishanBharda, It's my pleasure. You can definitely wait for an exact answer. I will also check and update you if I find any other solution. Thanks!

Comment: I think there is no other solution than your solution, so I am accepting your answer. Thank You.

Comment: However If anyone have other solution please post your answer.